# Load Model async using Task

Tags: wpf, mvvm, task-parallel-library

I'd Like to know How can I Load the model async from the service using Task.
Until now I used BackgroundWorker in the view model. 
Can someone give me a clear example?
Thanks.

Comment: This is a very general question. Have you looked at examples for the `async-await` model online? A Google search will give you millions.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange, I *think* they want to know how to announce state to the UI (or if there is a counterpart to the OnProgress callback), but that's a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load a model using the TPL, here's some indicative code...

```
        Task t = new Task(() =>
        {
            // broadcast start of busy state 
        });
        t.ContinueWith((z) =>
        {
            // load the model
        });
        t.ContinueWith((x) =>
        {
            // broadcast end of busy state
        });
        t.Start();
```

The first task lets the UI know that the app is entering a busy state so that the user can be supplied with visual clues.

The second task performs the heavy lifting.

The final task announces that the work is complete.  (x) can be queried to determine the appropriate UI message (it worked or it didn't work)

Task documentation is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.task